# Remove processing percentages from knitr product

Tags: r, knitr, r-leaflet

[image]

I am trying to remove the message seen in the picture.  Part of my RMD code needs to contact a website and get data.   The percentages from 1 to 100% keep showing up before the leaflet map.  Ive searched through the forum, but cannot figure out what else I need to turn to FALSE.  Currently the code chunk has the following options, `echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache=TRUE, message= 'hold', error=FALSE, purl=FALSE`.  I know its a simple fix, I just can't figure out the syntax.   Thank you for any guidance.

```
{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache=TRUE, message= 'hold', error=FALSE, purl=FALSE, options(dplyr.show_progress = FALSE)}

setwd("~/Desktop")
library(leaflet)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(tigris)
library(sf)

##load tigris districts
moLower <- state_legislative_districts("29", house = "lower")
moUpper <- state_legislative_districts("29", house = "upper")
```

Comment: Could you give us your code ?

Comment: Without additional information it is difficult to give you a definitive answer. Have you looked through the arguments here? https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-evaluation Perhaps put the code you use to retrieve the data in its own chunk, and set `include = FALSE`.

Comment: Do you know which function is printing the progress bars? Setting an option like `options(dplyr.show_progress = FALSE)` in your setup chunk might be enough to eliminate it altogether. The exact solution will differ from package to package (some functions like `data.table::fread()` provide a `showProgress` argument within the function call), but most packages provide some method to suppress this unwanted output.

Comment: i added the code above that i think is the problem

Comment: Thank you all very much.   Weihuang Wong's suggestion worked.   I put that section in its own block.